# stop Alarm Manager at specifc time

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I am triggering this alarm Manager using Service. So I want to stop the alarm Manager after 30 minutes, as it repeats after 10 minutes. Cancel doesn't work in my case
please help.

```
             AlarmManager alarmMgr0 = (AlarmManager) 
             getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            Intent intent0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
            schedule.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent0 = 
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent0, 0);
            Log.e(TAG, "SiteIN called");

            // Intent intent0 = new Intent(this, OldEntryRemover.class);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,26);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            if(Calendar.getInstance().after(calendar)){
        // Move to tomorrow
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }


    //set that timer as a RTC Wakeup to alarm manager object
            // alarmMgr0.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent0);
            alarmMgr0.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                    10000 * 60, pendingIntent0);

              try {
                 thread.sleep(30000 * 60);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           alarmMgr0.cancel(pendingIntent0);
```

Comment: how did you try to cancel at the first time ? share the code

Comment: I'm assuming you just need to call alarmMgr0.cancel(Intent0) depending on some business logic (after 30 min)

Comment: u please add the specific cancel part code here.@A

Comment: @Dan i have used that but it didn't work

Comment: @immadNaseem - I'd need to see your cancel logic to guide you any further

Comment: @Dan I have updated the code. Check at end

Comment: So youre waiting 30 min and then cancelling the whole alarm?

Can you provide a stacktrace of any errors?  Does it just not cancel and no error is produced?

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at the API and see if this is truly what you want.

> Schedule a repeating alarm. ***Note: for timing operations (ticks,
>   timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler***. If
>   there is already an alarm scheduled for the same IntentSender, it will
>   first be canceled.
>
> Like set(int, long, PendingIntent), except you can also supply a
>   period at which the alarm will automatically repeat. **This alarm
>   continues repeating until explicitly removed with
>   cancel(AlarmManager.OnAlarmListener).** If the stated trigger time is in
>   the past, the alarm will be triggered immediately, with an alarm count
>   depending on how far in the past the trigger time is relative to the
>   repeat interval.
>
> If an alarm is delayed (by system sleep, for example, for non _WAKEUP
>   alarm types), a skipped repeat will be delivered as soon as possible.
>   After that, future alarms will be delivered according to the original
>   schedule; they do not drift over time. For example, if you have set a
>   recurring alarm for the top of every hour but the phone was asleep
>   from 7:45 until 8:45, an alarm will be sent as soon as the phone
>   awakens, then the next alarm will be sent at 9:00.
>
> If your application wants to allow the delivery times to drift in
>   order to guarantee that at least a certain time interval always
>   elapses between alarms, then the approach to take is to use one-time
>   alarms, scheduling the next one yourself when handling each alarm
>   delivery.